# Import CSV file where last column has many separators

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The dataset looks like this:

```
region,state,latitude,longitude,status
florida,FL,27.8333,-81.717,open,for,activity
georgia,GA,32.9866,-83.6487,open
hawaii,HI,21.1098,-157.5311,illegal,stuff
iowa,IA,42.0046,-93.214,medical,limited
```

As you can see, the last column sometimes has separators in it. This makes it hard to import the CSV file in [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) using `read_csv()`. The only way I can import the file is by adding the parameter `error_bad_lines=False` to the function. But this way I'm losing some of the data.

How can I import the CSV file without losing data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would read the file as one single column and parse manually:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')

pat = ','.join([f'(?P<{x}>[^\,]*)' for x in ['region','state','latitude','longitute']])
pat = '^'+ pat + ',(?P<status>.*)$'

df = df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(pat)
```

Output:

```
    region state latitude  longitute             status
0  florida    FL  27.8333    -81.717  open,for,activity
1  georgia    GA  32.9866   -83.6487               open
2   hawaii    HI  21.1098  -157.5311      illegal,stuff
3     iowa    IA  42.0046    -93.214    medical,limited
```

Comment: btw do you mind explaining the code a bit? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding line 2 and 3

Comment: Line 2 and line 3 basically extract the corresponding groups. '?P<colname>` is regex for group naming, so that we have the correct names later on. `[^\,]*` means capturing all the non-comma characters. You can print `pat` after those two lines and paste it to [regex101](https://regex101.com) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the old-school technique with the `split` function? A major downside is that you'd end up losing data or bumping into errors if your data has a `,` in any of the first 4 fields/columns, but if not, you could use it.

```
data = open(file,'r').read().split('\n')
for line in data:
    items = line.split(',',4). # Assuming there are 4 standard columns, and the 5th column has commas
```

Each row `items` would look, for example, like this:

`['hawaii', 'HI', '21.1098', '-157.5311', 'illegal,stuff']`